# Procesar input con id dinámicos

Tags: php, javascript, sql, html5, backend

Espero poder explicarme bien y me puedan ayudar.
Estoy creando un sistema web para laboratorios clínicos. Estoy creando un modal donde se puedan agregar exámenes de laboratorio. Estoy tratando de hacerlo personalizable y que el usuario pueda elegir el tipo de input para cada estudio. El puede elegir que el tipo de input sea un select y eso le abre una nueva sección para que coloque los option de ese select. Esto esta realizado de manera dinamica con Javascript por lo que los input se generan dinamicamente. Aca muestro una imagen de ese modal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se aprecia en la imagen cada item se genera dinamicamente y cuando el select indica que es un seleccionable despliega una nueva seccion con las opciones del seleccionable las cuales si se le da al botón se multiplican indefinidamente según quiera el usuario.

Los item se insertan en una tabla con id autoincremento. Con PHP he logrado insertar los items en la base de datos, recibiéndolos como un array y con un ciclo for generar el insert.

Mi problema es cuando voy a insertar las opciones del seleccionable debido a que éstas van en otra tabla en la base de datos y se relaciona con el id del item. No he logrado asignarle la relacion de las opciones con ese id que se esta creando autoincrement en la tabla item. Hasta acá solo he logrado insertar las opciones pero solo me toma un id de los que se acaban de insertar con el item. Acá les muestro mi código PHP.

```
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
            $item = $_POST['item'][$i];
            $medida = $_POST['medida'][$i];
            $tipo_input = $_POST['tipo_input'][$i];
                            
            $insert2 = ("INSERT INTO estudios_item(nombre,tipo_input, medida) VALUES ('$item', '$tipo_input', '$medida')");

       if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $insert2)) {
         if($tipo_input == '3'){
           $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli); 
           $elemento_option = $_POST['elemento_option'];
      
           for ($i=0;$i<count($elemento_option);$i++){
             $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO estudios_optionsin (opcion, id_item) VALUES ('$elemento_option[$i]', '$last_id')");
           }
          }
        }
    }
```